# Forwarding and non-forwarding calls - Late Static Binding

Tags: php, oop, static, late-static-binding

> Note:
>
> Late static bindings' resolution will stop at a fully resolved static
> call with no fallback. On the other hand, static calls using keywords
> like **parent:: or self:: will forward the calling information**.
>
> Example #4 Forwarding and non-forwarding calls

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

```
<?php
class A {
    public static function foo() {
        static::who();
    }

    public static function who() {
        echo __CLASS__."\n";
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public static function test() {
        A::foo();
        parent::foo(); // what? - Why is resolved to C if B's father is A?
        self::foo(); // what? - Why is it not resolved in B?
    }

    public static function who() {
        echo __CLASS__."\n";
    }
}
class C extends B {
    public static function who() {
        echo __CLASS__."\n";
    }
}

C::test();
?>
```

Output:

```
A
C
C
```

I don't understand the use of `parent` and `self` in this example, could you please explain?

Comment: `A::foo()` works the same inside or outside the class, the context to `C` is lost. Both `parent` and `self` preserve the context though, which is `C`, so `C::who` is called in the end.

Comment: `self` and `parent` are relative to the actual class that the method is called from, not the class they're defined in. That's why it's called *late* binding. So if you do `B::test()` then `self` is `B`; if you do `C::test()` then `self` is `C`.

Comment: hi @Barmar, but in the doc says that "*Static references to the current class like self:: or __CLASS__ are resolved using the class in which the function belongs, as in where it was defined*"

Comment: @Barmar Coder23 is correct, `self` and `parent` do _not_ perform Late Static Binding, they refer to the current class definition, and its parent; the effect being observed is that they _forward_ the calling context, so that when you _later_ use Late Static Binding, with the `static::` prefix, PHP "remembers" that the context was originally `C`, even though a chain of `self` and `parent` calls have happened in between.

Comment: hi @deceze +1 But, `parent` and `self` preserve the context because later I use `static`, right? i.e., by default `self` refers to the defining class and `parent` to the parent class, right?

Comment: `parent::foo()` explicitly calls `A::foo`, while `self::foo` calls `B::foo` which in the end is also `A::foo`. Both preserve the *context* of `C` though, so `static::who` resolves to `C::who` in both cases.

Comment: thank you very much @deceze♦ +1, good of you to clarify this, I was doubting my knowledge of `parent` and `self` haha

Comment: hi @deceze♦ +1 `self::foo()` ends up calling `A::foo()` because `B` inherits from `A`, right?

Comment: @George Yes. Because `B` doesn't define any `foo` method and thus inherits `A`'s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During each call to a static method, the PHP runtime knows two pieces of information:

- The *calling context* - normally, the class which was referred to when you *called* the method; this is what `static::` refers to
- The class where the actual *definition* of the method is located; this is what `self::` refers to, and also what the magic constant `__CLASS__` will resolve to

---

Let's look at a simpler example first:

```
class A {
   public static function test() {
       echo 'Defined in ', self::class, '; called in ', static::class, "\n";
   }
}
class B extends A {
}
```

Calling `A::test();` will output `Defined in A; called in A` - `self` and `static` refer to the same class.

Calling `B::test();` will output `Defined in A; called in B` - although there is no method called `test()` defined in class `B`, PHP still knows that you called it while referring to `B`.

---

The "forwarding" comes in when you use `self::` more than once - PHP keeps track of the *original* calling context:

```
class A {
   public static function test() {
       echo __FUNCTION__,  ' defined in ', self::class, '; called in ', static::class, "\n";
   }
   public static function forward_test() {
       echo __FUNCTION__,  ' defined in ', self::class, '; called in ', static::class, "\n";
       self::test();
   }
}
class B extends A {
    public static function test() {
        echo 'this method is not called from forward_test()';
    }
}
B::forward_test();
```

Outputs:

```
forward_test defined in A; called in B
test defined in A; called in B
```

What happens here is this:

- PHP sets the calling context to class `B`, and looks for a method `forward_test()`
- The *definition* of `forward_test` is in class `A`, and outputs our first line of debug
- Now `forward_test` calls `self::test()`, and two things happen

  - the *definition* of `test` is looked up in *class A*, because that's where our *definition* of `forward_test` is
  - *but* the *calling context* is kept as class `B`, because `self` calls "forward" this information
- So `A::test()` is called, but with a calling context of `B`, resulting in our second line of debug

---

Internally, you can imagine the compiler replacing each method call with a `call_method` function that needs the target class name, the method name, and the calling context.

For `self::test()`, it can immediately replace `self` with the current class, which is `A`, and outputs something like:

```
call_method(targetClass: 'A', methodName: 'test', callingContext: $currentCallingContext)
```

Only when it runs, is `$currentCallingContext` defined, and forwarded.

An explicit call to `A::test()` explicitly defines both the target class *and* the calling context:

```
call_method(targetClass: 'A', methodName: 'test', callingContext: 'A')
```

Conversely, a "Late Static Binding" call to `static::test()` defines the target class based on the calling context:

```
call_method(targetClass: $currentCallingContext, methodName: 'test', callingContext: $currentCallingContext)
```

---

The same thing is happening with the `parent` calls in the example in the question:

- We call `C::test()`
- The definition is in `B`, but the calling context is `C`
- The call to `parent::foo()` resolves to the *definition* in `A`, but the *calling context* is forwarded, so is still `C`
- So we are running `A::foo()` with a calling context of `C`
- We then call `static::who()` which looks at the *calling context* to decide which method to run ("late static binding"), so it runs `C::who()`
- We are now in a method defined in class `C`, and the magic constant `__CLASS__` is the string `'C'`

---

An expanded example that shows some more information, and more variations:

```
class A {
    public static function foo() {
        echo __FUNCTION__,  ' defined in ', self::class, '; called in ', static::class, "\n";
        static::who();
    }

    public static function who() {
        echo __FUNCTION__,  ' defined in ', self::class, '; called in ', static::class, "\n";
        echo __CLASS__."\n";
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public static function foo() {
        echo __FUNCTION__,  ' defined in ', self::class, '; called in ', static::class, "\n";
        static::who();
    }
    
    public static function test() {
        echo __FUNCTION__,  ' defined in ', self::class, '; called in ', static::class, "\n";
        echo "A::foo():\n";
        A::foo();
        echo "B::foo():\n";
        B::foo();
        echo "C::foo():\n";
        C::foo();
        echo "parent::foo():\n";
        parent::foo();
        echo "self::foo():\n";
        self::foo();
    }

    public static function who() {
        echo __FUNCTION__,  ' defined in ', self::class, '; called in ', static::class, "\n";
        echo __CLASS__."\n";
    }
}
class C extends B {
    public static function who() {
        echo __FUNCTION__,  ' defined in ', self::class, '; called in ', static::class, "\n";
        echo __CLASS__."\n";
    }
}

C::test();
```

Outputs:

```
test defined in B; called in C
A::foo():
foo defined in A; called in A
who defined in A; called in A
A
B::foo():
foo defined in B; called in B
who defined in B; called in B
B
C::foo():
foo defined in B; called in C
who defined in C; called in C
C
parent::foo():
foo defined in A; called in C
who defined in C; called in C
C
self::foo():
foo defined in B; called in C
who defined in C; called in C
C
```

Comment: hi @IMSoP thank you. "*So A::test() is called, but with a calling context of B, resulting in our second line of debug*" -  that happens because `self::test()` resolves to `A::test()` inside `forward_test()`, right?, i.e. the functionality of `self::` and `parent::` remains the same, it refers to the defining class and `parent::` to the parent class (obviously), right?

Comment: @Coder23 Yes, because the code of `forward_test()` is physically inside the definition of class A, `self::test()` always means `A::test()`. It's just that *when it's called*, it's called with a magic parameter of the "calling context". Something like `call_method(className: 'A', methodName: 'test', callingContext: $currentCallingContext)`. Whereas writing `A::test()` explicitly would be `call_method(className: 'A', methodName: 'test', callingContext: 'A')`

Comment: great @IMSoP+1, we can say then, that always "by default" the calling context is passed, but it is only "visible", it only makes sense when you use `static::`, right?

Comment: @Coder23 Yes, that sounds like a reasonable way of looking at it.

Comment: excellent @IMSoP +1, this answer is worth gold, I didn't know these "hidden" uses of `parent` and `self` combined with `static` (I thought I already knew everything about LSB). One last question. `self::class`, `static::class`, `parent::class::` is a **reliable way** to access the class they resolve to, right?

Comment: @Coder23 I believe so; it's not actually very well documented (or I'm looking in the wrong place) but I believe `something::class` always uses the same resolution rules that `something::some_method()` would.

Comment: great @IMSoP +1, thanks a lot, definitely marked as best answer.

Comment: hi @IMSoP +1. In the example question, when executing `self::foo();`, does PHP realize that we use `static::` in `foo()`, or how does it get to class A if it initially resolves to `B::foo()`?

Comment: i.e., how does it "jump" from class B to class A if `self` is "fixed" to the current class it defines? @IMSoP

Comment: @GeorgeMeijer When you call `self::foo()` in class `B`, the compiler issues something like `call_method(targetClass: 'B', methodName: 'foo', callingContext: $currentCallingContext)` (the real implementation will be rather more complicated, I'm sure). When that runs, it needs to actually find some PHP code to run; it finds that `B` doesn't have an implementation for `foo`, but *inherits* the implementation from `A`; so that's the code that ends up running. The existence of `static::` makes no difference to how that plays out, `$currentCallingContext` is just passed along in case it's needed.

Comment: ok +1 @IMSoP, now I get it, I forgot that `B` inherits from `A`, that's why it ends up invoking `A`'s implementation, that has nothing to do with `self`, that's merely how inheritance works, right?